# What's with the spider?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the Dark Brotherhood's Sanctuary, near where Babette usually sits, there's a spider.  This spider is unique in that it is not aggressive, and does not even appear labeled or named when you approach it.

If you kill it, you will find that its corpse is named Lis and it carries the usual spider loot of Frostbite Venom and the occasional miscellaneous items.  It also has a Petty soul, which is fairly normal for a spider of its size.  And then, you'll quickly find all the members of the Dark Brotherhood (except Babette, as she is technically a child) are now aggro.  This can occur even if you were hidden when you made the kill.

However, I've yet to find any in-game source of a back-story for Lis.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: that spider was babette's friend, now she's gonna kill you :p

Comment: @yx. No she won't.  She'll just cower in the corner like the little girl she is... while she lets the rest of the Dark Brotherhood kill me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this wiki Lis is a member of the Dark Brotherhood, careful though as the wiki contains **spoilers**!

> Lis is a friendly frostbite spider and a member of the Dark Brotherhood. Lis dies when the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary is torched by the Penitus Oculatus during Death Incarnate.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lis)

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the relevant information here? You can even use the [spoiler markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/1782).

Comment: @JuanManuel I just put in an edit myself.

Comment: This is little more information than I already knew.  I want to know if there's any *history* behind this spider.

Comment: @Iszi the UESP people are very pro-active. If that is all they have found out about Lis then like as not, that is all there is.

Answer (score 0):

Lis is not Babettes it's Gabriel's. It dies when the sanctuary is burnt down.

Comment: Care to cite a source for the ownership?